# Is NOAA GFS winds aloft data available for applications?

Tags: weather

Where can I find the NOAA's winds aloft data in a form that I can use in an application? I plan to develop a software able to calculate the flight path of a lighter than air aircraft or drone using windspeed data from the [NOAA Global Forecast System](https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/data-access/model-data/model-datasets/global-forcast-system-gfs).

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, you might also try [earth.SE](http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: [This X-Plane plugin](http://x-plane.joanpc.com/plugins/xpgfs-noaa-weather) pulls NOAA data (which I believe includes the GFS winds aloft). It uses a program called [wgrib2](http://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/wesley/wgrib2/) to parse the information. The plugin is open source, that should get you started.

Answer (score 1):

See the following web page:

http://www.nws.noaa.gov/tg/general.php

This page describes getting started with the HTTP or FTP access to NOAA weather service APIs.

Answer (score 1):

The GFS products can be accessed at http://www.nco.ncep.noaa.gov/pmb/products/gfs/.  You can use the filename scheme they list to pull down current forecast products from FTP.  These are the native output grids in grib2 format.

Comment: I'll update this with OpenDAP sources if I find any when I get a chance later.

Comment: It looks like the OpenDAP access might not be realtime, but you can take a look at http://nomads.ncdc.noaa.gov/dods/NCEP_GFS/ and once you drill down to a specific file you can see the URL model for that access method.

Comment: There are quite a lot of data sets on that page. Which one is winds aloft?

Comment: @TylerDurden the one labelled "GFS - World Area Forecast System
Upper Air Forecast (1.25 degree resolution)" has winds from 850 mb up to 100 mb.  Also the "GFS - Binary Universal Form for the Representation of meteorological data (BUFR)
Inital BUFR Data Dump Files" contain winds aloft / upper air data that is suitable for use in the [BUFRLIB](http://www.nco.ncep.noaa.gov/sib/decoders/BUFRLIB/) program.   I haven't looked, but the data behind http://ensemble.ucar.edu/sounding.php (WRF ARW instead of GFS) might also be available somehow.